# csv to json parse returns invalid json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, fs

I have a csv file which I'm trying to convert to JSON. Even though it does convert it's not valid json.

Here is my csv:

```
"timestamp","firstName","lastName","range","sName","location"
"2019/03/08 12:53:47 pm GMT-4","Hi","Y'A","25-34","Parlour",""
```

Here is my code:

```
const csv=require('csvtojson');
csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then((jsonObj)=>{
    console.log(jsonObj)
});
```

I run it by node foo.js >> foo.json

Error is:

```
undefined:1
[ { timestamp: '2019/03/08 12:53:47 pm GMT-4',
```

Expected output:

```
[
 {
   "timestamp": "2019/03/08 12:53:47 pm GMT-4",
   "firstName": "Hi",
   "lastName": "Y'A",
   "range": "25-34",
   "sName": "Parlour",
   "location": ""
 }
]
```

Comment: Can you post the output?

Answer (score 0):

Work for me

```
let log = (s) => console.log(s);

const csv = require('csvtojson');
let str = 
`"timestamp","firstName","lastName","range","sName","location"
"2019/03/08 12:53:47 pm GMT-4","Hi","Y'A","25-34","Parlour",""`
csv().fromString(str).then(log);

/*
[ { timestamp: '2019/03/08 12:53:47 pm GMT-4',
    firstName: 'Hi',
    lastName: 'Y\'A',
    range: '25-34',
    sName: 'Parlour',
    location: '' } ]
*/
```

Works with file also. Check file content: commas, tabs, endlines.